# What is wrong with my prime number function in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've seen other examples where someone used "for x in range whatever" but our teacher hasn't taught us that yet.

```
def is_prime(y):
    x=2
    while x<=y:
        if x=y:
            return True
        elif y%x==0:
            return False
        else:
            x=x+1
```

Comment: `if x=y` should be `if x==y`. but that can't be the error as it is not valid python code...

Comment: I changed x=y to x==y and now it works for non prime numbers but not for prime numbers over 2.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the equivalent using the range function:

```
def is_prime(y):
    for x in range(2, y):
        if y % x == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to make it return false for y values less than 2 and had to change a x=y to x==y. This is my new program.

```
def is_prime(y):
    if y<2:
        return False
    else:
        x=2
        while x<=y:
            if x==y:
                return True
            elif y%x==0:
                return False
            else:
                x=x+1
```